# rails 5 remove whitespace from string only if it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 5 app, I have a name field (string) and a compressed name (string)

when a user signs up they enter their company name, i am trying to compress the name like so:

"My Company Name Here" - name

into

"mycompanynamehere" - compressed name

I am using this on the account model as an after_initialize call

```
  def compress_name
    self.compressed_name = name.downcase.split.join
  end
```

The problem with this is it just leaves `compressed_name` as `nil` if there are no whitespaces in the name field.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the bang `!` on `.downcase!`. And what does "it rolls back on account create" mean? It foils the validation and causes an exception?

Comment: yeah, if there is no white space in the name field, it just wont convert the name and leaves it set to nil in the database.. Ill update the question as i sorted out the rollback issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below one , tested

```
2.4.2 :013 > "My Company Name Here".gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase
 => "mycompanynamehere" 
2.4.2 :014 > "My CompanyNameHere".gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase
 => "mycompanynamehere" 
2.4.2 :015 > "MyCompanyNameHere".gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase
 => "mycompanynamehere" 
2.4.2 :016 > "mycompanynamehere".gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase
 => "mycompanynamehere"
```